# Sharepoint Online Login to a specific page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Is there a way to set which page appears when you login. I'd like to login into sharepoint then immediately be redirected to the about me section.

Basically when you go to the Office 365 login portal it redirects to outlook. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, there is domain registration page inside admin panel.
You can register a new domain or just make entry of your existing domain in that page.
Then, link the default site to your company url.

This is in brief.